# HTTP Post Authentication error

Tags: c#, http

Here is my code

```
string URL = "https://api.fastspring.com/accounts";

using (var wb = new WebClient())
{
    var data = new NameValueCollection();
    var contact = new NameValueCollection();
    data["contact"] = "first="+FirstName+"&last="+LastName+"&email="+Email+"&company="+Company;
    data["language"] = Language;
    data["country"] = Country;

    var headers = new WebHeaderCollection();
    headers["Authorization"] = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes("username:password"));
    headers["User-Agent"] = "request";
    //headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";

    wb.Headers = headers;
    var response = wb.UploadValues(URL, "POST", data);
    return (System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response)).Split('"')[3];
}
```

My problem is that i keep on getting a 401 error saying unauthorised. For one, is my authentication syntax correct? also is my entire setup for sending an HTTP request to the server correct?

here are some useful resources about the fastspring api if it would help:

http://docs.fastspring.com/integrating-with-fastspring/fastspring-api/accounts#id-/accounts-Createanaccount

http://docs.fastspring.com/integrating-with-fastspring/fastspring-api

Comment: I think it should work if you used `headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + System...` (what you have)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto thanks for the reply, i added thos and still the same thing.